# returning custom data type (class?) in java

Tags: java, methods, types, return

### Background

I wrote a java method to navigate between days, months and years. This is an example of one Method:

```
    public MyDate nextMonth(){
    if (month<12){
        month++;
        setDay(1);
        return MyDate();

    }
    else
        nextYear();
        return MyDate();
}
```

MyDate is the class name. The constructor looks like this:

```
public MyDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        setYear(year);
        setMonth(month);
        setDay(day);
    }
```

The Method is supposed to return values like this:

```
MyDate d1 = new MyDate(2012, 2, 28);
System.out.println(d1);             // Tuesday 28 Feb 2012
System.out.println(d1.nextDay());   // Wednesday 29 Feb 2012
System.out.println(d1.nextMonth()); // Thursday 1 Mar 2012
System.out.println(d1.nextYear());  // Tuesday 1 Jan 2013
```

### Situation

So, I wrote the code for all three methods except I cannot get it to return a MyDate type - which is needed for other methods and toString and so on.

### My Question

How do I get these kinds of methods to return a type MyDate?

Comment: **these methods** which methods? already you are doing it for `nextMonth()` why cant you apply the same for other methods?

Comment: methods such as the one in question: nextMonth()

Comment: Hmmm, instead of `return MyDate();`, return `this`, that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement should return current modifying object, not the new MyDate object, so change the return method to return current object using `this`, as shown below

```
public MyDate nextMonth(){
    if (month<12){
        month++;
        setDay(1);
        return this;               //return current object
    }
    else
        nextYear();
    return this;               //return current object
}
```